# Updating voice_nav.py in pocketsphinx to fix Turtlebot2 issue

Tags: ros, navigation, turtlebot2, turtlebot, pocketsphinx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I noticed an issue with the voice control example, voice_nav.py, in pocketsphinx. I'm new to ROS and don't know who to tell to suggest a fix. Could someone tell me how to go about notifying someone about this issue?

Here is the issue as I understand it. In pocketsphinx, voice_nav.py publishes on the /cmd_vel topic to move the robot. I think this works fine for the original turtlebot, but the turtlebot2 with a Kobuki base needs this published on /cmd_vel_mux/input/navi topic.

To get the pocketsphinx samples running on my turltebot2, I had to change line 44 of voice_nav.py from

> ```
> self.cmd_vel_pub = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=5)
> ```

to

> ```
> self.cmd_vel_pub = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel_mux/input/navi', Twist, queue_size=5)
> ```

But I think this fixes it for the turtlebot2, but breaks it for the original turtlebot.

So, how do I go about notifying someone of this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229389/updating-voice_nav.py-in-pocketsphinx-to-fix-turtlebot2-issue/) by [tgibbons](https://answers.ros.org/users/18810/tgibbons/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rather than modifying the code directly, you can change topic names with [remapping](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments):

```
rosrun my_package my_node cmd_vel:=cmd_vel_mux/input/navi
```

Who to notify depends on where the sample is hosted. If it's a book, you should contact the author (maybe by opening a ticket on their bug tracker, if they have one). If it's a wiki page, you may just be able to update the wiki page with a different command for the turtlebot2 .

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0